# How to remove a reference autoId value in a UItableView from Firebase tree in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, tableview

I have a tableview loaded with messages from Firebase. Storing the data is easy, but trying to delete a specific node with an autoID is troubling me.

I know I have to get a reference to the first node which in this case is `Posts`, but how do I get the next node as a reference? Which in this case this node is an autoId. Below is the code.

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if editingStyle == .delete {


        print(messages)
        print(indexPath.row)            

        var messageIndexRef = postData[indexPath.row]

        print(messageIndexRef)


        ref?.child("Posts").child("how do I get this auto ID?").removeValue(completionBlock: { (error, ref) in

            if error != nil {

                print("error \(error)")

            }
        })

       MessagesTableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

Comment: You will need to keep a dictionary that maps each row/index of the table view to the key of the corresponding item in Firebase. If you build this dictionary while you're reading the data from Firebase (the same moment you get the value), you can then use the dictionary when the user clicks a row.

Comment: Thanks Frank. Ok, so I create this dictionary when im getting the value. And when the user clicks a row that autoId will be attached to that value hence I can then use this as the string to pass into "child(key)". This dictionary, is it a class variable so I can access it throughout the entire class at will?

Comment: Yes. As far as I can see from the snippet you shared, it would at the same level `postData`. Once hold the `key` the other the `value` of each row.

Comment: thank you. will work on it.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to keep a dictionary that maps each row/index of the table view to the key of the corresponding item in Firebase.

As far as I can see from the snippet you shared, it would at the same level `postData`. One holds the key the other the value of each row.

If you build both dictionaries while you're reading the data from Firebase (the same moment you get the value), you can then use the dictionary with keys to determine the `key` of the row the user clicked on.

Comment: awesome.. thank you for this..I get what your saying. Just need to put it in code now.